# select a date with where clause

Tags: sql

```
select Artikel from liste_vorbestellungen 
where Termin_fuer_Abholung = 2017;
```

I have a table and I have to select all articles with the date 2017, this already works, my probelm now is, that my dates in the table are given with day, month and year, how Can I select the articles with the year 2017 when not only the year was given?

Comment: This can be done by using the function that returns the date's year but that function may change depending on the RDBMS you are using, so please add a tag specifying it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is better use to explicit comparisons to dates rather than functions.  Why?  Because that allows the optimizer to use indexes.  So, although Mureinik's answer is correct, the following can (under some circumtances) have better performance:

```
select l.Artikel
from liste_vorbestellungen l
where l.Termin_fuer_Abholung >= '2017-01-01' AND
      l.Termin_fuer_Abholung < '2018-01-01' ;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `liste_vorbestellungen(Termin_fuer_Abholung, Artikel)`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your question with any [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms), but most of them support the `year` function to extract a year from a date:

```
SELECT Artikel
FROM   liste_vorbestellungen 
WHERE  YEAR(Termin_fuer_Abholung) = 2017;
-- Here^
```

**EDIT:**

As @ a_horse_with_no_name pointed out in the comments, the standard ANSI-SQL approach would be to use the `extract` function:

```
SELECT Artikel
FROM   liste_vorbestellungen 
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Termin_fuer_Abholung) = 2017;
-- Here^
```

Comment: In standard SQL this would be `extract(year from termin_fuer_abholung)`  (Oracle, Postgres and Firebird do not support `year()` only the standard `extract()` function)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name learned something today, thanks! Edited into my answer.